# WP7 GeoCoordinateWatcher in the background

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, geolocation

I'm wanted to wright a app which would alarm you when you are getting near a location.
I wanted to use the GeoCoordinateWatcher with PeriodicTask, but the test Task is invoked every 15min if i'm not mistaken. Can I somehow force the PeriodicTask to invoke more frequent? Or is there something else I can do to use the GeoCoordinateWatcher in the background which is not invasive for the UX. The app should work like for 2-3 hours and i like to update the location like every 5 minutes.

Comment: Can you show us the code you're using now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible for now. You only can run your application in foreground under lock screen to save battery life.

Comment: Just wanted to know this. Thank you for the fast response.

Answer (score 0):

Register to the `PositionChanged` event of `GeoCoordinateWatcher` and set a low value of property `MovementThreshold` of `GeoCoordinateWatcher` to get the position changed events more frequently.

According to MSDN

```
    This property specifies the minimum change in position that must take place 
before the PositionChanged event is raised.
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Timer to Start your Watcher every 5 minutes, just don't forget to Stop it too and so save the battery.